# Search contacts for multiple phone numbers

Tags: android

I have an array of phone numbers that I want to match against the contacts present on the phone. What is the most efficient way of doing so? So basically the output should be an array of contacts that matched those phone numbers.

I know about `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup`, but as far as I know it only looks up one number at a time. Is there a more efficient way of searching for multiple numbers in one go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some code from my poject. Look on it, and edit how you want. :)

```
        final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        String selection  = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
        final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,  null, sortOrder);

        int Size = cur.getCount();
        con = new Contact[Size];
        for (int z = 0; z < Size; z++)
            con[z] = new Contact();

        conArray = new ArrayList<Contact>();


        if (Size > 0) 
        {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                String Sid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Sid);
                InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),my_contact_Uri);            
                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
                Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                        null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = ?", new String[] { Sid }, null);

                con[CountCon].Add(name);
                if (my_btmp != null)
                    con[CountCon].SetImage(my_btmp);
                else 
                    con[CountCon].SetImage(bm);

                while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    con[CountCon].Add(pCur.getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                }
                if (con[CountCon].GetNumber(0).isEmpty())
                    con[CountCon].Add("none");

                conArray.add(con[CountCon]);

                CountCon++;

                pCur.close();
            }
        }
        cur.close();
```

Comment: Contact is a class where I put contact Name, photo, numbes

Comment: You're just retrieving all the phone numbers here. What I need is a lookup on contacts for multiple numbers. Quite different, really.